# free language/database for standalone application

Tags: programming-languages

Can you advice me please on a "free" language and database that I can use to create a standalone application e.g. simple HR application w/ (forms,reports and queries) that I can copy and use in my flash memory ?

Comment: what platform(s) does it need to run on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost any language will work. And most languages these days are free both as in beer and as in liberty. As for the database, definitely SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 0):

Mono + C# + SQLLite